# Issue in calling Successfactors API

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

My issue is that to apply the below process, I need a username of approver, by which I can find sessionID and authorization. But that username I can get by only logging into successfactors web console. But I can't go every time on web console and then apply the above process programmatically. So, can anyone have solution of my problem?

I have already done the below task. I am taking username of X person i.e. **xyz** as reference. You can change this with any approver.

```
https://apisalesdemo8.successfactors.com/odata/v2/approveWfRequest?wfRequestId=1234L&username=xyz

SOAP UI:
Username: xyz,
Password: "password"
Company ID: "companyID"
Then JSESSIONID generated by using above credentials in SOAP UI.…….

Restlet Client:
Authorization:
Username: xyz@companyID
Password: "password"
Then got the response:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:WfRequestActionResponsexmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<d:elementm:type="SFOData.WfRequestActionResponse">
<d:status>success</d:status>
<d:wfRequestIdm:type="Edm.Int64">1234</d:wfRequestId>
</d:element>
</d:WfRequestActionResponse>

I have applied above credentials and process on 1234 workflowID, the status changed from PENDING to COMPLETED.
```